# Chrome Driver Needs to be available in the path error on Mac

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am running OS X 10.9.4 on my laptop, with Chrome 40.0.2214.94 and Selenium 2.44.0, which I installed for Python 2.7 with easy_install. My code is this basic code from a selenium walkthrough:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

But when I run this I get an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/masongardner/Desktop/Selenium_tester.py", line 17, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 66, in start
    "ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path. "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path. Please download from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver
```

As the documentation specifies, chrome is at this location on my machine:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

What can I do to get around this problem and begin to retrieve data from certain pages as I had planned? If you could be very explicit about code changes or location changes, as I am not the most well versed in computing!

Thanks everyone, and I hope my question isn't too simple!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ChromeDriver is a binary file that interfaces WebDriver with Chrome. If you have WebDriver's libraries installed, and Chrome installed, you still need the ChromeDriver binary in a location that WebDriver can find it.

As the error message indicates, you need to get the binary from here:

```
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

And then place the binary file somewhere on your PATH. Optionally, you can tell WebDriver where the binary is by setting a system property. I would start off by placing the binary somewhere on your PATH and get more specific/complex if you need to.

/usr/bin is on the global path for OS X, so that's a good place to put the file. Plus, it would be available to any user on the computer. You can open up that folder by opening a Finder window, choosing the Go -> Go To Folder in the menu, then entering in /usr/bin  (you'll probably be asked for your password as it's a system location.) Then just copy the ChromeDriver binary file into there.

Comment: As of El Capitan (OS X 10.11) adding a file to one of the system paths is not possible anymore, thanks to "System Integrity Protection". This means it is not possible to put chromedriver in the global path. Therefore we need to change the global path that is used in eclipse. Changing the bash_profile is not enough for this. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

Use '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'. This worked for me:

```
import selenium
import os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chromedriver = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/users/login')
```

Comment: i move the driver to `/usr/local/bin/` and it works!

Answer (score 4):

To work around this issue on **Mac OXS El Capitan 10.11.6**, I have added a copy of chromedriver executable file to:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver
```