# Open browser on Mac with python

Tags: python, google-chrome

How to describe the path to chrome on MAC?
I used this code:

````
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('../chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
time.sleep(5)  # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5)  # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()```

I got error: **DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('../chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.**
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome Driver Needs to be available in the path error on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307469/chrome-driver-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path-error-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

The "error" is just a warning; your code should work with it. Still, it is good to fix deprecation errors, because the code might stop working soon. This should not issue an error:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# modify if different
chrome_path = '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'

chrome_service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(chrome_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service)
```

Of course, you can also download `chromedriver`. If you don't want to worry about where your Chrome or `chromedriver` is, you can use [`webdriver_manager`](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) which will automatically dowload the driver for you if necessary, and supply you with the path:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
```